# Is "Virtual Dedicated Server" a correct name?

Tags: virtualization, vps, vds

I've been searching for differences between servers and came accross VPS and VDSs. Which are accordingly Virtual Private Server and Virtual Dedicated Server. For example in [GeeksForgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-vps-and-vds/) they say that they use different virtualization techniques. Namely VPSs use OS lever virtualization and VDSs use "paravirtualization".

As my logic says to me Dedicated Server must mean a separate server machine dedicated to me. So any virtualization applied to this server breaks the rule of "dedication".
So if this is the case Virtualization on a server must make it "Virtual Private Server". I think this name is more applicable to a virtualized server.

So. Why there are two different things such as VPS and VDS. I am very confused.

P.S. [In this link](https://cloud.google.com/learn/what-is-a-virtual-private-server#section-4) Google says that there are 3 kinds of hosting: Shared, VPS, and Dedicated (without the word "virtual"). So can I come a conclusion that VDSs are actually a misnaming for VPSs?

Comment: Most providers will give you anything you want if dedicated. The business model for non-dedicated is if you can jam 120 virtuals on a server using paravirtualization that is more profitable that 100 virtuals.  The reality is customers don't have a way of measuring this or assigning an SLA to it, so it isn't meaningful. Also the most popular providers are selling you a service that meets a specification. They aren't selling you "paravirtualization". Nearly all of these are throttled so that any and all technology, dedicated/non-dedicated, paravirtualized/non will provide the same performance.

Answer (score 2):

The terms have nothing strictly to do with with the type of hypervisor used, though you may see patterns.

The only real difference is that with a VPS you are highly likely to be running on hardware shared with other users, whereas with a VDS you will have the full resources of the server, minus any hypervisor - if used - overhead.

The actual type of hypervisor plays no real part in this.